# SSRS ReportServer DB reporttypes configuration question

Tags: database, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder, reportserver

I am in the process of categorizing reports so the reporttypeid is shown in the catalog table in the reportserver db. It ties to the reporttype table to get the category. Is there a way to set the report type in report builder so that when the RDL files get uplaoded to SSRS they will populate this???

I have not tried anything yet